# How can I change the existing crystal report to a new one from programming

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm using visual studio 2010 and also crystal report v13.0.18.2192 I have a crystal report from this location

```
path2=Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,@".\CrystalReporInv.rpt");
```

this work correctly but I need to add a new report to the same location

path2=Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,@".\CrystalReportSalesInv.rpt");

but this throws an exception

Comment: what exception? think carefully on making sure you give us enough information that we have a chance to help you, otherwise this will get closed

Comment: "It says invalid report file path"

Comment: But I have tried this way also path2 = "@E:\\Projects\\sinha Hardware\\SILVA MOTORS\\CrystalReportSalesInv.rpt");

Comment: Provide more information by pasting the exception

Comment: Invalid report file path

Answer (score 0):

rpt file must be located in that folder; Is it? Spelling? Permissions?

Comment: In Which folder?

Comment: Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,@".\CrystalReportSalesInv.rpt")
Consider also displaying the result of that expression and doing a sanity check on it.